# How to avoid spam replies from bumping bbPress topic freshness?

Tags: wordpress, spam, bbpress, akismet

We have a growing bbPress forum integrated with Akismet to filter out spam, which works quite well for both spam topics and also replies to existing topics. However, even when a reply gets marked as "spam" and held in moderation, that bbPress topic's freshness is still bumped and so it goes to the top of the Recent Topics widget and such...

When users click on these "recent" topics, there is in fact no new replies published, because they are being held in the spam queue by Akismet. How can we avoid this from happening?